# Laravel Ajax not working, The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, routes, get

I try to test Ajax with Laravel.
I wrote test code which work in php but I have problem to move it to Laravel.

My script :

```
function refresh() {
                
                
                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
                        {
                            document.getElementById("refresh").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            
                        if (this.responseText=="refresh")
                        {
                            location.reload();
                        }
                        
                        }
                    };
                    xmlhttp.open("POST", 'refresh', true);
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf token"]').content );
                    xmlhttp.send(refresh);
```

My route:

```
Route::post('refresh', [ZamowieniaController::class, 'ajax']);
```

In my controller:

```
public function ajax(Request $request)
    {
    return test;
    }
```

I get error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

Comment: Quotation can be an issue, use the same quotation, you mixed the single/double quotation

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: ok, i think i solve this problem. I change POST method to GET.

Comment: This is not actually the right solution, change this line too `xmlhttp.open("POST", 'refresh', true);`

Comment: Yes i change POST to GET in route and in script